# Laravel DB::raw query using multiple WHERE clauses

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So I have a query that I would want to add some extra conditions to.

Query:

```
$providers = BusinessDetail::select(
    'business_details.name as description', 
    DB::raw('SUM(review_details.param_value) / COUNT(review_headers.id) AS avgUserReview')
)
->leftJoin('review_headers', 'business_details.id', '=', 'review_headers.business_detail_id')
->leftJoin('review_details', 'review_headers.id', '=', 'review_details.review_header_id')
->leftJoin('rate_params', 'review_details.rate_param_id', '=', 'rate_params.id')
->groupBy('business_details.id')
->get();
```

I would want to add the following to the query DB::raw query `DB::raw('SUM(review_details.param_value) / COUNT(review_headers.id) AS avgUserReview')` alone.

```
->whereIn('rate_params.id', [1, 3, 4, 5])
->where('review_details.param_value', '<>', NULL)
->where('review_details.param_value', '<>', '')
->where('review_headers.review_status', '=', 1)
```

So that the query reads `'SUM(review_details.param_value) / COUNT(review_headers.id) where the four WHERE clauses included in this alone.

How do I go about that?

Anyone?

Comment: Not really clear...

Comment: @TsaiKoga how can I add the for where conditions to the `DB::raw('SUM(review_details.param_value) / COUNT(review_headers.id) AS avgUserReview')` ?

Comment: just add them after leftjoin

Comment: @TsaiKoga if I add them there, they will affect the others.... I want them to apply to `'SUM(review_details.param_value) / COUNT(review_headers.id) AS avgUserReview'` alone

Comment: you don't have `groupby`, after `sum()/count()`, it will become one record, so add condition still one record, and you just select `description` and `avg`, not really know affect the others.

Comment: Sorry @TsaiKoga .... I have a `->groupBy('business_details.id')`

Comment: Please mention your DB structure and what you want to achieve as a result. There might not be a need for so many joins and where clauses. Also, what do you mean by it will affect `business_details.name as description`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use selectRaw to do that.

[Documentation selectRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-methods)

Just added in your query raw:

```
->selectRaw('SUM(review_details.param_value) / COUNT(review_headers.id) AS avgUserReview')
->whereIn('rate_params.id', [1, 3, 4, 5])
->where('review_details.param_value', '<>', NULL)
->where('review_details.param_value', '<>', '')
->where('review_headers.review_status', '=', 1)
```

Comment: But this will affect the others ... Including `'business_details.name as description',` Can it be specific for only `'SUM(review_details.param_value) / COUNT(review_headers.id) AS avgUserReview'`?

Answer (score 0):

```
->selectRaw('SUM(review_details.param_value) / COUNT(review_headers.id) AS avgUserReview')->select('business_details.name as description')->whereIn('rate_params.id', [1, 3, 4, 5])->whereNotNull('review_details.param_value')->where('review_headers.review_status', 1);
```

You can use two selects method or one select Raw Method and mention as many column you require in it. as @juancruzbarrios.job mentioned it like this

```
->selectRaw('SUM(review_details.param_value) / COUNT(review_headers.id) AS avgUserReview , business_details.name as description')->whereIn('rate_params.id', [1, 3, 4, 5])->whereNotNull('review_details.param_value')->where('review_headers.review_status', 1)
```

2nd thing you are writing two where condition for one column which can be shorten to

Comment: What if you do not want the condition to apply to the rest of the picks i.e the WHERE conditions should only apply to `'SUM(review_details.param_value) / COUNT(review_headers.id) AS avgUserReview'` only but not to the rest.

Comment: Then you use use DB::raw('select SUM(review_details.param_value) / COUNT(review_headers.id) AS avgUserReview from review_details where conditions') if still unclear ping me to chat